# How can I get the list of commercial flights between 2 countries over the past x days?

Tags: air-travel

How can I get the list of commercial flights between 2 countries over the past x days?

---

**Note to close voters**: the question is different from [Historical flight data outside of the USA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44263/1810): as mentioned in the question and in a previous comment, I'm looking for a way to **search by country**.

---

The question triggered by [this comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/158680/residents-of-which-countries-are-currently-allowed-to-enter-japan/158682?noredirect=1#comment397199_158682)  from [JonathanReez](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/9009/jonathanreez):

> But does the Japanese government actually intend for people to travel from Tanzania or are they merely omitted because there aren't any direct flights? – JonathanReez♦ ↵ 6 mins ago

Comment: For past flights, you probably want Flight Radar or something like that - future flights are easier, as you can track them via ITA Matrix (https://matrix.itasoftware.com/#view-flights:research=TYODAR-DARTYO;out=2020-09-01;stay=7 - no direct flights)

Comment: @Moo Thanks, do any of these support searching for a country instead of airport code?

Comment: Google Flights kinda does, but not really.

Comment: @Moo also many future flights end up being canceled nowadays :/ so preference for what actually happened in the past.

Comment: Yeah, you aren't going to get a good source on that unfortunately, since there doesn't seem to be a good curated public source of data for this - airlines aren't required to report it to one single body so stats stay internal (there may be reporting to individual aviation bodies for countries, but I cant find anything about reporting to the IATA, UN etc).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Historical flight data outside of the USA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44263/historical-flight-data-outside-of-the-usa)

Comment: @Arthur'sPass no, as mentioned in the question and in a previous comment, I'm looking for a way to search by country.

Comment: @Franck It seems to me you need to start with historical data ('past X days'). Once you've got that the searching it should be straightforward. Or is this a question about how to search data? The latter belongs elsewhere.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass 1) It's not straightforward to me but if it is to you then you're welcome to post it as an answer 2) the question question isn't about how to search data: I'm looking for an existing solution, not building it myself.

Comment: You most probably have to build it yourself, since all API and data sources I know allow filtering granularity by IATA/ICAO/ATC. I think only ADS-B data sources will allow you to build queries that you want to make.