# Can a dual French-US citizen get a visa exemption when entering Japan?

Tags: japan, us-citizens, covid-19, visa-free-entry, french-citizens

[IATA](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php) for Japan states:

5. Visa exemption for nationals of Andorra, Argentina, Austria, Bahamas, Barbados, Belgium, Brunei Darussalam, Bulgaria, Costa Rica, Croatia, Czechia, Cyprus, Denmark, Dominican Rep., El Salvador, Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Guatemala, Honduras, Hungary, Iceland, Indonesia, Iran, Ireland (Rep.), Israel, Italy, Korea (Rep.), Latvia, Lesotho, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malaysia, Malta, Mexico, Monaco, Netherlands, Norway, Peru, Poland, Portugal, Romania, San Marino, Singapore, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Suriname, Sweden, Switzerland, Thailand, Tunisia, United Arab Emirates, Uruguay and Vatican City (Holy See) is suspended.

The list contains France and not the United States. Can a dual French-US citizen get a visa exemption when entering Japan, (assuming they don't come from one of the [147 countries from which one aren't allowed to enter Japan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/158682/1810) or can't enter for some other reason)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you point out, one must distinguish 1) the suspended visa exemption for certain nationalities and 2) the entry ban for persons arriving from certain countries.

Provided not arriving from a "banned" country, US citizens can indeed enter visa-free.

Comment: Thanks! Does being a French citizen in addition of being a US citizen matter?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt No, you're classified by the passport you present unless a dual Japanese national. This is the default in general, which does however have exceptions such as notably the VWP restrictions for dual nationals of certain Muslim countries